# Locally square integrable (local) martingales

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales, stochastic-analysis, local-martingales

I'm reading Protter and sometimes he says "locally square integrable martingale", and sometimes he says "locally square integrable local martingale", and I wonder if these two are the same.

Protter's definition is a property holds locally for $X$ if there are $T_n$ increasing to $\infty$ such that $X^{T_n}1_{T_n>0}$ has the property.

Then a local martingale is an adapted cadlag $X$ which is locally a martingale.

Protter also proves that a cadlag $X$ which is locally a local martingale is a local martingale.

Now I try to parse "locally square integrable local martingale". If $X$ is such that it is locally a square integrable local martingale, in particular $X$ is locally a local martingale, and hence is a local martingale. Thus the question reduces to is "(locally square integrable) + (local martginale) = locally (square integrable martingale)"?

I think they are the same because if $T_n$ makes $X^{T_n}1_{T_n>0}$ a martingale, and $S_n$ makes $X^{S_n}1_{S_n>0}$ square integrable, then $T_n \wedge S_n$ should make $X^{T_n \wedge S_n}1_{T_n \wedge S_n > 0}$ a square integrable martingale. Is this line of reasoning correct or am I missing something?

Comment: @ nullUser : You are right the sequence $R_n=T_n \wedge S_n$ is indeed an annoucing sequence of the property "Square Integrable + Martingale". The fact that it tends almost surely to infinity is obvious, it stays a Martingale under $R_n$ because of the optimal stopping theorem (or th 48-a of chap I Protter's), and it is square integrable because of conditional Jensen inequality. It goes like $E[X_{S_n}^2|R_n]\geq E[X_{S_n}|R_n]^2=X_{R_n}^2$ (by optimal stopping and martingale property) then take expectation on both side to get $E[E[X_{S_n}^2|R_n]]=E[X_{S_n}^2]\geq E[X_{R_n}^2]$) best regards.

Comment: @TheBridge I have come across this same question but I don't follow your notation. What is the process $X$? To use optimal stopping and martingale property we need to consider $X$ as $X^{T_n} 1_{T_n>0}$, but then $X_{S_n} = X^{T_n}_{S_n}$ is just $X_{R_n}$, so we have an equality here.

Comment: Hi X is just X, $S_n$ is the ann. seq. for loc. L^2, and T_n loc. Mart. The inclusion  loc(L^2+Mart.)=C in (loc L^2)=A$\cap$ (loc Mart.)=B is the goal. For this we want to check if $R_n=T_n \wedge S_n$ is an ann. seq for C for  X in A and B.So in your comment the equality $X_{S_n} = X^{T_n}_{S_n}$ is not ok. Is that clearer ?