# Process with multiple local properties as process with locally multiple properties

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stopping-times, local-martingales

This is motivated by reading the notion "locally square integrable local martingale".
Parsing that I arrive at a process $X$ for which two sequences of stopping times $(\sigma_n)$ and $(\tau_n)$ exist, for which $\sigma_n\uparrow \infty$ and $\tau_n\uparrow\infty$ and for which $X^{\sigma_n}$ is square integrable and $X^{\tau_n}$ is a martingale. Can we find a single localizing sequence $(\rho_n)$ for which $X^{\rho_n}$ is both a martingale and square integrable?

More generally, given multiple local properties just as above for a process $X$, can we find a single localizing sequence $(\rho_n)$ for which the stopped processes $X^{\rho_n}$ has all those properties (and additionally is a bounded process provided the process is sufficiently semicontinuous)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your first question: Yes, you can. But not in the "natural" way to define $$\rho_n := \sigma_n \wedge \tau_n$$ because square integrability is not guaranteed for the stopped process in general. But it is if you have square integrability of the maximum process $$X^*_t := \sup_{s\le t} |X_t|$$ Then it follows for any stopping time $\rho$ that $$\begin{align*} E[X^2_{t \wedge \rho}] &= E[X^2_t1_{t\le \rho}] + E[X^2_\rho1_{t > \rho}] \\ &\le E[X^2_t] + E[X^2_\rho] \\ &= E[X_t^2] + E[X_t^*] < +\infty\end{align*}$$

So then square integrability becomes stables under stopping.

Fortunately martingale property is stable under stopping so if $M$ is a martingale and $\rho$ an almost sure finite stopping time we have that $M^\rho$ is a martingale as well.
This leads to the useful fact that if we have a localizing sequence $(\tau_n)$ s.t. $X^{\tau_n}$ is a martingale and we define $$\sigma_n = \inf \{t \ge 0\;|\; |M_t| > n\}$$ then $\sigma_n$ is a stopping time and with $$\rho_n := \tau_n \wedge \sigma_n$$ we get that $M^{\rho_n}$ is a bounded martingale hence square integrable.

So, to summarize: For properties which are stable under stopping you easily can combine all related stopping time by considering the infimum of all stopping times.

For the other ones you still can construct a stopping time so that you get a bounded martingale and most of the properties hold for bounded martingales.

If you have property which is neither stable under stopping nor valid for bounded martingales you have to find another way.

Comment: Thank you, that was helpful (in particular the very last paragraph). Regarding the definition of $\sigma_n$: I think it needs to say $\vert M\vert \geq n$ and and also I think that only $\sigma_n\to\infty$ if $M$ is continuous. Or, maybe right-continuity is sufficient, I am not sure... If right-continuity is not sufficient we still haven't solved my example, right?

Comment: Well, càdlàg should be sufficient, right, and every martingale is càdlàg modulo modifications, so it could be fine...

Comment: I just saw the comment under this  [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1635406/locally-square-integrable-local-martingales) and remembered you claiming square integrability not to be stable under stopping. Doesn't this comment invalidate that statement? Thanks, again!

Comment: Hi, first you are right it was meant $|M| \ge n$, I will fix that. To square-integrability: The comment doesn't invalidate the statement. There it's used that the martingale property is stable under stopping to show square integrability still holds. But square integrability itself is not stable under stopping. To see this take a continuous square integrable process $X$ where the maximum process $$X^*_t := \sup_{s\le t} |X_t|$$ is NOT square integrable and consider the stopping time $\tau = \inf\{0 \le s \le t | |X_s| = X^*_t\}$. Then it holds $X^\tau \equiv X^*$ … tbc

Comment: But this doesn't mean that for ANY stopping time square integrability is not stable. It just show that it does not hold in general. If you have additional properties (like martingale property) it's probably possible to show a stopped process is still square integrable. This was also mentioned in my answer before that having the martingale property is often useful because this property IS stable under stopping and this may help you especially connected with Jensen's inequality. But you weren't asking for martingale property but for general properties…

Comment: Yes, thank you, you made it very clear!

Comment: And one more thing to mention. If you already have a martingal which is square integrable then it follows by Doob's maximal inequality that the maximum process itself is square integrable. Then ofc (see answer above) it follows directly,  that the process square integrability is stable under stopping.

Comment: @Gono So do you actually show that for cadlag adapted processes, being locally a martingale ensures local square integrability as well? I don't see where in the proof you use locally square integrability. So I am confused because then it seems like locally square integrable local martingale is redundant.